# VBA Excel macros stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office, macros

I'm getting [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQfsY.png) when trying to execute any macro in Excel (i.e. it won't execute anything, not even MsgBox)

Pretty sure it has something to do with Windows Update, Defender, missing/corrupt files, conflict with other files/software/drivers (AcrobatPDF, NVIDIA?), incorrect permissions or anything else?

I did sfc /scannow and it did find some corrupted files and successfully fixed them

I did try uninstalling and reinstalling Office but no luck in getting it fixed

It might be worth mentioning I get BSODs quite often, possibly due to faulty RAM/disk/drivers (CRC errors when unpacking rar/zip files or installing msi/cab/packages etc); not sure if it has anything to do with the VBA not functioning

How do I diagnose the issue?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Macro and the command line,,`Dim Wb As Workbook`,, It can be used as Standarad as well as Module also !! Could you share the Workbook with us to examine the Macro?

Comment: @Rajesh I'm assuming there is a missing reference? If yes then which one?  https://uploadfiles.io/e05hsvd0

Comment: ,, unfortunately can't reach to the site,, if possible use Drop Box or mail to me, find my ID at Profile!

Comment: @RajeshS emailed you the file

Comment: check mailbox I've attached the Wbook,, read instructions also.

Comment: @RajeshS I had to resort to resetting Windows as it was apparently a corrupt Office/Windows causing the issue

Comment: Great job @Dan ,, keep asking ☺